# Change Calculator with exact type of change given

Tags: python, calculator

the instructions are

> Create a program that allows him to input a certain amount of change,
>   and then print how how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies are
>   needed to make up the amount needed. For example, if he inputs 1.47,
>   the program will tell that he needs 5 quarters, 2 dimes, 0 nickels,
>   and 2 pennies.

I didn't really know how to do this but I gave it a shot. I'm really unsure of what to do.

```
print "Change Calclator"

quarter = .25
dime = .10
nickel = .5
penny = .1

moneygiven = raw_input("Enter how much money given: ")
citem = raw_input("How much did the item cost?: ")
moneygiven = float(moneygiven)
citem = float(citem)
moneyback = moneygiven - citem

qmb = moneyback % quarter
partialtotal = moneyback - qmb * quarter 
dmb = partialtotal / dime
dpartialtotal = partialtotal - dmb * dime
nmb = dpartialtotal / nickel
npartialtotal = dpartialtotal - nmb * nickel
pmb = npartialtotal / penny
ppartialtotal = npartialtotal - pmb * penny

print "You need %s quarters, %s dimes, %s nickels, %s pennies." % (qmb, dmb, nmb, pmb)
```

when run with 20 in moneygiven and 19.45 in citem it gives this

```
Change Calclator
Enter how much money given: 20
How much did the item cost?: 19.45
You need 2.2 quarters, 0.0 dimes, 0.0 nickels, 0.0 pennies.
```

Comment: You would find this much easier if you worked in `int` pennies, rather than `float` dollars - floating point numbers do things that may surprise you (for example, `((20 - 19.45) % 0.25)` gives `0.050000000000000044`, and I get `You need 0.05 quarters, 5.375 dimes, 0.0 nickels, 0.0 pennies.` overall).

Comment: I dont think your code matches your output.  If I do `qmb = moneyback % quarter` I get .05 not 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing @jonrsharpe's comment, you should work with `int` variables holding pennies. The point here is that you have an *integer* amount of coins with *float* values, and you're mixing them when dividing, thus getting weird values. Also take into account that you should use the proper division operator.

Here a working version:

```
print "Change Calclator"

quarter = 25
dime = 10
nickel = 5
penny = 1

moneygiven = raw_input("Enter how much money given: ")
citem = raw_input("How much did the item cost?: ")
moneygiven = int(float(moneygiven) * 100)
citem = int(float(citem) * 100)
moneyback = moneygiven - citem

qmb = moneyback / quarter
partialtotal = moneyback - qmb * quarter 
dmb = partialtotal // dime
dpartialtotal = partialtotal - dmb * dime
nmb = dpartialtotal // nickel
npartialtotal = dpartialtotal - nmb * nickel
pmb = npartialtotal // penny
ppartialtotal = npartialtotal - pmb * penny

print "You need %s quarters, %s dimes, %s nickels, %s pennies." % (qmb, dmb, nmb, pmb)
```

Comment: You should make the jump to `int` as early as possible, otherwise you could end up a penny out (as `int` truncates, rather than rounding).

Comment: I see it was kind of obvious sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the // operator instead / operator.
Another thing it that you put penny= .1 And that is the same of penny=0.10. You should use 0.01

// Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.

Example:

```
 a=.25
.55//a = 2.0
```

Code Working

```
print "Change Calclator"

quarter = .25
dime = .10
nickel = .05
penny = .01

moneygiven = raw_input("Enter how much money given: ")
citem = raw_input("How much did the item cost?: ")
moneygiven = float(moneygiven)
citem = float(citem)
moneyback = moneygiven - citem

qmb = moneyback // quarter
partialtotal = moneyback - qmb * quarter 
dmb = partialtotal // dime
dpartialtotal = partialtotal - dmb * dime
nmb = dpartialtotal // nickel
npartialtotal = dpartialtotal - nmb * nickel
pmb = npartialtotal // penny
ppartialtotal = npartialtotal - pmb * penny

print "You need %s quarters, %s dimes, %s nickels, %s pennies." % (qmb, dmb, nmb, pmb)
```